# How to solve Symfony 5 Omines Datatables problem

Tags: datatables, symfony5

When using custom query in omines datatables on a Symfony 5.3 project like so:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder;
...

$table->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
    'entity' => User::class,
    'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
        $builder
            ->select('u')
            ->from(User::class, 'u')
            ->where('u.roles LIKE :role')
            ->setParameter('role', '%ROLE_AGENT%')
        ;
    },
]);
```

I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\Admin\AgentController::App\Controller\Admin{Closure}() must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder, instance of Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder given.

I've tried using customized criteria as described in datatables docs, but getting the same error.

My import is correct, so why this error?

Comment: It really isn't, since it's the `ORMAdapter`, it *does need* an `ORM\QueryBuilder`, not a `DBAL` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading: datatables query function should in fact be given instance of Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder, not Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder that causes the error.